# Oracle Create Table as Select * from Another_Table same table space

Tags: oracle

I didn't design the DB so don't judge me on this.

I have a log table that is receiving *A LOT* of entries. I only need to keep a day or so on this this log table. My initial thought was:

In a single transaction:
1. rename the log table
2. create the original log table from the renamed log table
3. commit the trx and life goes on

The second time this happens I drop the renamed table and do it all over again. This will run as an Oracle job once a day.

The original question:
Would anyone know if I specify a table space name in table #1 like so:

```
create table "my_user"."first_table" (pkid number, full_name varchar2(50)) nologging tablespace "my_custom_tablespace";
```

Then I do something like:

```
create table second_table as select * from first_table where 1=2  -- because I only want the structure
```

Will my second_table be in the same table_space?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: No. `second_table` will be created in whatever your default tablespace is. It doesn't care what `first_table`'s tablespace is.  But why don't you try it?  That would have been faster than writing up a question.

Comment: I wouldn't know how to check where what table space was used for the new table. Thank you however for your help on this one.

Comment: Here is how you can check: `select tablespace_name from user_tables where table_name = 'SECOND_TABLE'`

Comment: Excellent... Thank you.

Comment: A negative 1? That's harsh. I did spend some time reading the dense documentation on Parallelizing Table Creation (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables003.htm#i1009052). No where does it specify what was said in the comment that sstan provided. I was hoping for someone to provide an argument or a parameter where it would create the second table in the same table space.

Comment: @OneClutteredMind - if you want the second table created in the same tablespace as the initial table, use `create table my_user.second_table ...`

Comment: @mathguy: That won't work, unless OP wants `my_user`'s default tablespace to be used.  But that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Just taking a step back, DDL cannot be part of a transaction.  DDL issues an implicit commit before and after the statement executes.  Renaming the log table will be two transactions.  Creating the new table will be two transactions.  There will be nothing to commit when that's over.  This would cause downtime for your application (assuming it needs the log table to exist) for however long it takes to copy the data you want to retain over.  If something goes wrong, you couldn't roll back.  That seems much riskier than just doing a delete to remove the old data.

Comment: Justin Cave, thanks for your response. Looks like I'll have to go the long route for implementing the rolling log table. I was hoping for something quick that wouldn't cause a bunch of log entries. I suppose my strategy would be create the rolling log table with "NOLOGGING" and truncate before every insert while using the /*+ APPEND */ hint.

Comment: I'm not quite sure that I follow what the "long way" is or how it would not lead to either data loss or downtime for the application (that's probably a separate question anyway so I don't want to get too deep into the weeds in comments).  Are you really sure that the simple strategy of deleting old data every day really causes problems for you?  Are you licensed to use partitioning so you could just drop the older partition every day?

Comment: Nice idea - I'm fairly new to Oracle. I come from an MS SQL world. The log table is really just to check the time merge statements are taking. The company I'm contracting with has an Oracle RAC with licensing to do anything - even coffee. :)

I'm sort of working with what was given to me. Probably something I can research. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Enterprise Edition with partitioning, then a simpler solution is to go with an interval partitioned table, with one partition per day. Then truncate the partitions when you don't need them.

If not, then go with two tables, a synonym to point to the 'current' one that is being inserted into, and a view that selects from a union of the two tables. The nightly job would truncate the 'old' table and switch the synonym to make it the 'new' one.